# Building V8 on Windows does not output v8_base.lib

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I want to build V8 and embed it in a C++ program to use SWIG to allow a Javascript app to call into the C++ library. However, after following the steps for building V8, I am missing some of the important libs for linking to V8 (e.g. V8_base.lib):

1. fetch v8
2. cd v8
3. git pull origin
4. gclient sync
5. python tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release
6. ninja -C out.gn/x64.release

I have DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN = 0 and GYP_MSVS_VERSION = 2019.
My args.gn is the following (I have built with and without the last line):

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
is_component_build = false
v8_static_library = true
is_clang = false
use_lld = false
```

After a successful build, I find that there is no v8_base.lib file under out.gn\x64.release\obj as all of the docs indicate there should be. Strangely, I see a v8.stamp and v8_base.stamp files, but no corresponding *.lib. What am I missing? Are these libraries no longer needed for embedding into a C++ program?

Answer (score 4):

### Overview

[The instructions on the website to build a sample app](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) are a bit better than whatever instructions you're following now

The `v8_base.a` target was removed from the `build.gn` file [here](https://github.com/v8/v8/commit/7e896fe59602c68f0b864e5e3dafbef3841903bd#diff-4eaebbcd1dc0da11e3a3ce488290bfc6L1657) in april, 2019

### Prerequisites

1. Python2 (Python3 For newer versions)
2. Git
3. [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)
4. G++ (or clang)

### Updated instructions for building v8 (on linux/macos)

Here are the steps I followed today to successfully compile and run v8

1. Install google's depot tools: `git clone "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git" ./depot_tools`
2. Add the depot tools to your path `export PATH=$(pwd)/depot_tools:$PATH`
3. If you are building on windows, be sure to set `DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0` as an environment variable
4. Download v8: `fetch v8` OR `fetch --no-history v8`
5. Move into the v8 directory `cd v8`
6. Generate a release for your system (probably): `tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.release`
7. Run `gn args out.gn/x64.release` to the following build arguments:

```
is_debug = false
target_cpu = "x64"
use_custom_libcxx = false
v8_monolithic = true
v8_use_external_startup_data = false
is_clang = {whether or not you're using clang}
```

(* More [here](https://gist.github.com/AlexMasterov/d2e344f5f54d72f37b014a1066f4bf8e))

1. gn automatically regenerates build files when you close your editor
2. Build v8 (slow) `ninja -C out.gn/x64.release`

### Using your newly created v8 library

In the root of your project directory create a folder called `src` and inside that folder create a new file `main.cc` which looks like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);

  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate); // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate); // Create a new context.
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context); // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.

    {
      v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Object.keys({ h: 1, e: 2, ll: 3, o: 4, _: 5, w: 6, or: 7, l: 8, d: 9 })", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(); // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
      v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked(); // Compile the source code.
      v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked(); // Run the script to get the result.
      v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result); // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
      printf("%s\n", *utf8);
    }
  }

  isolate->Dispose();
  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  return 0;
}
```

1. Build your source using the new monolithic library created in the ninja build: `g++ -Iv8/include src/main.cc -o bin/my_program -lv8_monolith -Lv8/out.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++11`

For this to work, your file structure should look something like

```
depot_tools
v8
src/main.cc
```

It will create a new executable in your `bin` folder called `my_program` which you can execute directly `./bin/my_program`